# How to update Vuex store from v-model input in case of v-for

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I've say 10 objects in an array like
    `policies = [{name:'a',text:''},{name:'b',text:''},....]`

They're iterated using v-for to show label A: Inputbox with text property binded as v-model.
I want to trigger a mutation whenever a policy's text changes in v-model.

Here's the fiddle link for it.
https://jsfiddle.net/dmf2crzL/41/

Comment: You mean you want to know when a text inside of the input changes? Your question and demo code has nothing to do with vuex.

Comment: I want to commit a mutation so i'd want an action when the value is changed in v-model

Comment: why not use @keyup on the inputs and trigger your commits inside a function/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We assume you want to use `v-model` for a `2-way` binding along with `Vuex` store.

Your problem is that you want Vuex store in strict mode.

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  // ...
  strict: true
})
```

so all of your mutation should go through Vuex store and you can see it in Vue.js devtools.

Method 1: We can avoid the Vuex error by using the cloned object and use watcher to commit the mutation.

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  strict: true,
  state: {
    formdata: [
      { label: 'A', text: 'some text' },
      { label: 'B', text: 'some other text' },
      { label: 'C', text: ' this is a text' }
    ]
  },
  mutations: {
    updateForm: function (state, form) {
      var index = state.formdata.findIndex(d=> d.label === form.label);
      Object.assign(state.formdata[index], form);
    }
  }
});
    
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store: store,
  data () {
    return {
      //deep clone object
      formdata: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.$store.state.formdata))
    };
  },
  computed: {
    formdata() {
      return this.$store.state.formdata
    }
  },
  watch: {
    formdata: function(form)
      this.$store.commit('updateForm', form);
    }
  }
})
```

Method 2: You can use computed get/set to commit your mutation as per the [vuex doc](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/forms.html)

```js
computed: {
  message: {
    get () {
      return this.$store.state.obj.message
    },
    set (value) {
      this.$store.commit('updateMessage', value)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you do a computed setter/getter with an index (i.e. in a v-for loop)?

Comment: I'm not sure Method 1 would work. It would trigger a warning because you have a same-named formdata as a computed property and as a data property creating the problem of which "this.formdata" is it referring to.

Answer (score 2):

another way that I found useful:

1. replace the v-model to a (v-on) function
2. that function triggers a mutation
3. the mutation ("function" in the store) change a value in state
4. a getter ("computed" in the store) "listens" to the change in the property value and changes accordingly.

this is an example of how to filter cards with Vuex (instead of v-model:

input that triggers a function "updateFilter":

```
    <input type="text" placeholder="filter" v-on:input='updateFilter'>
```

a function (method) that triggers a mutation (commit):

```
  methods: {
updateFilter(event){
  this.$store.commit('updateFilter', event.target.value);
}
```

in the store.js, a mutation that changes data (state):

```
mutations: {
    updateFilter (state, filter) {
        state.filter = filter; 
    },
```

the state:

```
state: {filter: ""}
```

and the getter (computed) that "listens" to the change in the state.

```
getters: {
    filteredGames: state => {
        //your filter code here
          return filtered;
        })
    },
```

and finally, the component that needs to be filtered has this computed (getter):

```
  computed: {
filtered() {
  return this.$store.getters.filteredGames;
}
```

Comment: How is the initial value set?

Comment: @Dean initial value could be set by `:value` property

Answer (score 0):

Mine library vuex-dot simplifies reactivity (and, sure, v-model) usage on vuex store

https://github.com/yarsky-tgz/vuex-dot

```
<template>
  <form>
    <input v-model="name"/>
    <input v-model="email"/>
  </form>
</template>

<script>
  import { takeState } from 'vuex-dot';

  export default {
    computed: {
      ...takeState('user')
        .expose(['name', 'email'])
        .dispatch('editUser')
        .map()
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: @yaroslave does your library allow access to state of nested objects in store..?

Comment: @Wikki yes, it is, you can use dots, eg. 'users.0.email'